# Forumula IFS 1*1=1

Tags: excel, if-statement, google-sheets, nested-if, ifs

Im looking for someone to get me a full explanation about what exactly does 1*1=1 in the following formula.

```
=IFS(L72=I71,"YES",L72=J71,"YES",L72=K71,"YES",1*1=1,"NO")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it doesnt matter what you use if the result will be always true. examples:

```
1*1=1
1=1
TRUE
9*9=9
502=502
"x"="x"
16=4*4
```

any of them will work

Answer (score 0):

Good Day,

The way IFS function works is:

1. Checking the first condition in the first parameter and returning
   the value in the second parameter if it is True and if it is not
2. Then checking the second condition in the third parameter and returning the value in the fourth parameter if it is True and if it is not
3. Then Checking the third condition in the fifth parameter and returning the value in the sixth parameter if it is True and if it is not
4. Last thing it is checking the 1*1=1 condition in the seventh parameter which is always True and returning the eighth parameter, in this case it is considering the last parameter as the else part as used in the "IF" function

Comment: For the point #4, would it be the same if I use false instead of 1*1=1?

Comment: no, it will be same if you use TRUE